# Firestore Security Rule: can I limit write access to part of the data within a document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a document with dataset like below

```
{
   "name":"fefefefe",
   "days":[false,false,false,false,true],
   "members":[
       {"email":"eee@ff.com","id":"aaaaaaaa","name":"Mark1"}, 
       {"email":"eee2@ff.com","id":"bbbbbbbb","name":"Mark2"}, 
   ],
}
```

Can I set the firestore security rule that user cannot change the email and id?

For other fields, user can change it.

any good reference of previous post?

Comment: In your rule, just check that the field value has not changed between `resource.data` and `request.resource.data`.